# table contact has no column named time (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this error: 
table contact has no column named time (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contact(time,day,status) VALUES (?,?,?) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method
please help me if you know the solution.

my code is :

```
public  void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT," + KEY_DAY + " TEXT)");

}
```

and I add data in this way:

```
     button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           String A="aa";
           String B="bb";
           String C="cc";

           Contact contact = new Contact(0,A, B ,C);

           try {
               dbHandler.createContact(contact);
           } catch (Exception e) {                


               Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
           }

        });
```

Comment: Please edit your post so we can see the value of KEY_TIME and your dbHandler.createContact-Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs just a space. instead of " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," I wrote 
" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " and this error is solved.